# Make a line graph of the datas in database in Android app

Tags: android

I am making an Android project where there will be a set of data values in local database. Now taking all data values, for that certain items, I want to represent those by a line graph. How can I do so?
Are there any packages in Android to easily do so and represent in a activity?

Comment: you can check this http://www.androidviews.net/2013/07/holographlibrary/ i never used it but someone posted this on here and i bookmarked it

Answer (score 1):

Graph Library available into Market:

1. [Graph Demo](https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView-Demos)
2. [Achartengine-bar-chart](http://www.truiton.com/2013/04/android-tutorial-drawing-achartengine-bar-chart-with-example/)

Answer (score 0):

use following library

1. Achartengine [Achart](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/)

   2.HoloGraphLibrary[HoloGraphLibrary](https://bitbucket.org/danielnadeau/holographlibrary/wiki/Home)